# Is there any way to retrieve metadata from an AIFF file in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, metadata

I am trying to get the metadata from AIFF files in Ubuntu. I want the album art as well as the title and artist.

Is there any utility or solution available to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found **mediainfo** which seems to be able to handle the aiff files correctly.

```
sudo apt-get install mediainfo mediainfo-gui
```

To retrieve the album art (I think it's MIME encoded) use the `-f` command line option, or set *Debug* to *Complete* in the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use `ExifTool`](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to read the metadata from `AIFF` files, as well as a wide variety of other formats.  You can call `exiftool [yourfile]` to get a listing of any tags in the file's default format.

You can use this list of the [available metadata/tags here](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/AIFF.html), as well as the [`exiftool` CLI documentation](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#option_summary) to extract a particular tag.

---

Lastly, there's a lot of GUI-based music/media players which have the ability to read/write metadata from sound files, in addition to adding or extracting album art.  Your Linux distribution may already include such a program, or you might want to consider some alternatives (e.g. [Audacious](http://audacious-media-player.org/)).